# Write into workbook with extension other than xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I use `openpyxl` to write into Excel with pandas and as long as I'm working on a file I'd like to use a different extension for it. The usual convetion is to appand `.lock`, but `openpyxl` denies to cooperate with it and complains that the extension is invalid.

Is there a way to disable this check or altenatively to make it accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! This is how it goes:

```py
from pandas.io.excel import _OpenpyxlWriter

class ExcelWriterWithLock(_OpenpyxlWriter):
    supported_extensions = (".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".lock")
```